# How to check if only two checkboxes are checked?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm building a quiz app for practice and i wish to check if two checkboxes are checked(and add 1 to a variable if they are checked). Here is my code:

```
CheckBox questionFiveAnswer_1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.question5B);
boolean correctAnswer_5_1 = questionFiveAnswer_1.isChecked();

CheckBox questionFiveAnswer_2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.question5D);
boolean correctAnswer_5_2 = questionFiveAnswer_2.isChecked();
```

I don't want to link the remaining checkboxes to the MainActivity.Java file. Is there anyway i can check without accessing the remaining checkboxes?
Thanks!

Comment: If you don't need the rest, that is, you don't care about their state, then you just link those checkboxes you need and ignore the rest. If they are both checked, use a simple `&&` to compare both and do whatever you want if true. If false, either none or one of them is checked. If true, they are both checked.

Comment: I've already done that but it added 1 to the variable when all the boxes were checked

Comment: @Nicholas check my answer

Comment: If you want to check if exactly one is checked then you have to check if one is checked and the other is not. See Nicholas' answer below.

Answer (score 0):

> i wish to check if two checkboxes are checked(and add 1 to a variable
>   if they are checked)

You can use counter to archive

```
double checkBoxCounter = 0;

    if((questionFiveAnswer_1.isChecked()) && !(questionFiveAnswer_2.isChecked()) || !(questionFiveAnswer_1.isChecked()) && (questionFiveAnswer_2.isChecked()))
    {
     checkBoxCounter++; // if is checked, add 1 to checkBoxCounter 
    }
```

Comment: It still adds 1 if all the checkboxes are checked

Comment: please post your code here

Comment: int checkBoxCounter = 0;
        if (questionFiveAnswer_1.isChecked()){
            checkBoxCounter++;
        }
        if (questionFiveAnswer_2.isChecked()){
            checkBoxCounter++;
        }

Comment: answer edited..

Comment: it's the same thing as the code i posted in the comment above.

Comment: we need to see more code